# Java randInt switch function issue

Tags: java, random

I am kind of relatively new to java and am working on a project for class. This is a portion of the system and i have been getting errors in this piece.

```
 public class NumberTest
    {
        private static void main( String[] args )
        {
        }
        static private char GenerateNumber() 
        { 
             int gennumber = 0;
                while(gennumber < 3)
                {
                char returnChar = ' ';
                switch(randInt(0,9))
                {
                    case 0:
                        returnChar = '0';
                        break;    
                    case 1:
                        returnChar = '1';
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        returnChar = '2';
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        returnChar = '3';
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        returnChar = '4';
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        returnChar = '5';
                        break;            
                    case 6:
                        returnChar = '6';
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        returnChar = '7';
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        returnChar = '8';
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        returnChar = '9';
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Error Random int outside expected values");           
                }
                return returnChar;
                    System.out.println(GenerateNumber());
                gennumber++;
                }  
            }

    }
```

The error I am receiving is:
Test.Again.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                        switch(randInt(0,9)
symbol:    method randInt(int,int)
location:  class NumberTest

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call undeclared function **randInt**. It means you must first write this function in your class and then use it.

However you may use java.util.Random:

```
Random rand = new Random();
switch(rand.nextInt() % 10)
...
```